# JQuery open dialog

Tags: jquery, .net

I have following markup on aspx page where one of the  element should open jQuery Dialog. Here is the markup,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr align="center" >
        <th align="center"><span><a href="#" style="color:Blue;background-color:#f2f2f2;" >Open Dialog</a></span></th>
    </tr>
    .......
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm trying following JQuery function to open dialog box but not working,

```
$("th span a").click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

           $("#dialog").dialog({
               buttons: {
                   "Close": function () {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               }
           });

           $("#dialog").dialog("open");
       });
```

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: well first off, by not setting the option `autoOpen: false`, you're trying to open it twice. As is written, you don't need the line `$("#dialog").dialog("open");`, however, would probably be wise to leave it and move your dialog initializing outside of the click event

Comment: Try to add `ContentPlaceHolder_` before `dialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, do you have an element with the ID `dialog`? Secondly, you're creating an already open dialog on the click event and then trying to open it again.  I would suggest a rewrite like:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'th span a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            'Close': function(e, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

If the dialog **`doesnt`** already exist, then you could rewrite as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dlg;
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'th span a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
            dlg.dialog("open");
        });

        dlg = $('<div />', { id: 'dialog' }).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'Close': function(e, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Of course, this second way means creating and appending HTML to the Dialog `DIV`, else it will be empty ... forever!

Comment: Thank you @bilbob533. Your code works fine.. Yes I have element with dialog ID.